# rails form with new method in another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Hello :) So i want to put a new form Review in my show page Internship.

Internship table

```
 create_table "internships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "adress"
    t.string "zipcode"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "specialty"
    t.string "organization"
    t.string "population"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "title"
    t.string "cursus"
    t.float "duration"
    t.string "region"
    t.integer "remuneration"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_internships_on_user_id"
  end
```

Review table

```
create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.float "notation"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "review_user_id"
    t.bigint "review_internship_id"
    t.index ["review_internship_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_review_internship_id"
    t.index ["review_user_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_review_user_id"
  end
```

This two models are linked together. If you do @internship.reviews, you have all the reviews for an internship and if you do @review.review_internship, you have the internship of that particular review.

I don't know how to change my new form Review, so that i can make a new review, in my page show internship. I get a NameError in Internships#show, Is it possible to do this ? The new review is only linked with the id of the internship, so i think it's best if the form new review is in the show page internship. I don't know if there is a better way to do this...

Review new form

```
  <%= form_with(model: review, local: true) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :notation %>
    <%= form.number_field :notation %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :review_internship %>
    <%= form.number_field :review_internship %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Review controller

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /reviews/new
  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

  # GET /reviews/1/edit
  def edit
    current_user_must_own_review
  end

  # POST /reviews
  # POST /reviews.json
  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.review_user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.save
        format.html { redirect_to @review, notice: 'Review was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @review }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

So basically my question is, can the Internship controller call the create method of the controller Review ?

I hope my question is understandable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You want to have the form for a new review on your internship show page. Remember that creating a new record normally requires two actions in Rails - new and create. `New` would be the page that normally has the form and `create` is the action once the form is submitted.

Now if you want the form on the internship show page you don't need the `new` action anymore. You can move the form itself into the view for internship show and if you use any instance variables in this form they go into the `interships_controller#show`.

```
# controllers/internships_controller.rb
...
def show
  ...
  @review = Review.new
end
```

```
# views/internships/show.html.erb

<%= form_with(model: @review, local: true) do |form| %>
...
```

Now, when you hit submit on the form, it will still go to `reviews_controller#create`. This is because of some "magic" happening with this first line in the form. Load your page in the browser and inspect the form in the inspector. It will look something like this (plus a lot more attributes).

```
<form action="/reviews" method='post'>
```

This means once you hit submit it will make a post HTTP request which goes to `/reviews`. If you set up your routes right, you can check with `rails routes` in the terminal and see this will go to the `reviews_controller` to the `create` action. So there you can handle the logic of creating a new review.
If you are a beginner I would recommend you to delete the whole `respond_to` block and do this instead:

```
# controllers/reviews_controller.rb

 def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.review_user = current_user

    if @review.save
      redirect_to @review, notice: 'Review was successfully created.' }
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

And here you have the choice to redirect back to the internships show page.
But how do you find out which internship this review was just made for? You just created a field in the form which is fine - but not very intuitive for the user. He/she is on the internship show page and now has to fill in which internship this review is for? You should look at nested resources next, but this would be a bit much for this question.

One more hint: you named the foreign key for the internships in the reviews table `review_internship_id` which is a bit unsual which you can see when you call `@review.review_internship`. Just `internship` is fine and then you can do `@review.internships` - short and easy.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation !! Yeah, i am new to rails and programming in general, you're so cool, thank you !

For the review_internship_id, i am working on it. I added this line in the review controller, so that rails would know about the review user

 @review.review_user = current_user

But i'll search for the review_internship. I just did it for the form and it worked, so thanks a lot

Comment: Perfect, if you want to, you can accept my answer and upvote it :)